# Encode/Decode password to xml

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I'm working on an App that requires you to login, doesn't need something complicated, so I've made an XML file called users.xml and saved user/pass in nodes, now when encoding them to base64 it works fine, I can see it encoded in the xml file, but when I use the decrypt function, it crashes with the error "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array."

Here is my adduser code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace k9record
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadComboUser();
        }

        public static string encode(string text)
        {
            byte[] mybyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            string returntext = System.Convert.ToBase64String(mybyte);
            return returntext;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PATH = "user.xml";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            //If there is no current file, then create a new one
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(PATH))
            {
                //Create neccessary nodes
                XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
                XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is an XML Generated File - Ather");
                XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("users");
                XmlElement user = doc.CreateElement("user");
                XmlElement UserID = doc.CreateElement("UserID");
                XmlElement Password = doc.CreateElement("Password");



                //Add the values for each nodes

                UserID.InnerText = textBox2.Text;
                Password.InnerText = textBox1.Text;


                //Construct the document
                doc.AppendChild(declaration);
                doc.AppendChild(comment);
                doc.AppendChild(root);
                root.AppendChild(user);
                user.AppendChild(UserID);
                user.AppendChild(Password);

                doc.Save(PATH);
            }
            else //If there is already a file
            {
                //Load the XML File
                doc.Load(PATH);

                //Get the root element
                XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                XmlElement user = doc.CreateElement("user");
                XmlElement UserID = doc.CreateElement("UserID");
                XmlElement Password = doc.CreateElement("Password");

                //Add the values for each nodes
                UserID.InnerText = textBox2.Text;
               // Password.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
                Password.InnerText = encode(textBox1.Text.ToString());


                //Construct the Person element
                user.AppendChild(UserID);
                user.AppendChild(Password);


                //Add the New person element to the end of the root element
                root.AppendChild(user);

                //Save the document
                doc.Save(PATH);
            }

            //Show confirmation message
            MessageBox.Show("User Registered");

            //Reset text fields for new input
            textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc1.Load("user.xml");
            foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc1.SelectNodes("/users/user"))
            {
                if (node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                }

            }
            xdoc1.Save("user.xml");
            MessageBox.Show("User Deleted","Deleted");
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            loadComboUser();
        }

        private void loadComboUser()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("user.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/users/user");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText))
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my login code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace k9record
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadComboUser();
        }


        public static string decode(string text)
        {
            byte[] mybyte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            string returntext = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(mybyte);
            return returntext;

        }

        internal void Login()
        {



            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("user.xml");

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/users/user"))
            {

                String Username = node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText;
                String Password = node.SelectSingleNode("Password").InnerText;
                if (Username == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() && Password == decode(textBox7.Text))
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
            }
        }

        private void loadComboUser()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("user.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/users/user");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText))
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("UserID").InnerText);
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

can someone please guide me?

Comment: i've also tried 'string returntext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mybyte);'

Comment: Why are you using ASCII in one place, and UTF8 in the other?

Comment: Seriously, never ever ever store passwords in a  form that allows them to be decoded. Store them as a salted hashes and apply the same hash to the entered password to match against stored values. No if's; no but's.

Comment: @ Ron it was a mistake, i used utf in both cases, i got the same error

Comment: @DavidArno any links to an example?

Comment: @atherakber, please read https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store base64 encoded data in your xml, So in `Form2`(your login form), either you should **encode** the text (textBox7) and compare it with value in xml, or **decode** the value in xml and compare it with textBox7(which is in plain text).

Your current code takes the value in textBox7 decode it(which is not encoded) and compare with the value in xml

*PS: I assume this code is only for learning purposes...*

Comment: yes its not a commercial software, its just for a charity who looks after sick dogs, 

can you please explain how would i encode it again?

Comment: No I can't because I don't understand what your are asking. What is unclear in my answer?

Comment: " you should encode the text (textBox7) and compare it with value in xml"

Comment: @atherakber Like in Adduser case, take the password, apply the same algorithm and compare the result with the one stored in xml.

Comment: something like this?

http://pastebin.com/aRBs2xKZ

Comment: @DavidArno there is no website, it's just a simple exe file, and the app will be used by the vet only

Comment: @atherakber, OK, I'll calm down now :)

Comment: @atherakber No, You have an encoded string in xml file. So What you have to do? encode the textBox7 and compare the value with the one in xml. No need for decode :). ..  I got tired.........